# Storage in Cloud Functions: How to get the download-url?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Inside a cloud function, how can I get the download-url of a storage file?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const storage = admin.storage();
```

Using this storage object I can do `storage.bucket().file(path).getMetadata()` but the returned metadata does not contain the firebase-signed-download-url.

[The docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) says to create a reference and do `reference.getDownloadURL()`. Only thing is that this does not seem to work with the storage object returned from the firebase-admin package.

Comment: The question that this is allegedly a duplicate of was asked/answered before firebase-admin was able to access Firebase Storage. The current solution is similar, but you can use `admin.storage().bucket()` to create a bucket rather than requiring `@google-cloud/storage`.

Comment: In other words, OP, you were very close, but you should have used `.getSignedUrl()` rather than `.getMetadata()`.

Comment: @Sidney The firebase-admin module just provides a thin wrapper on top of @google-cloud/storage.  It doesn't do anything different, in practice.